# Check if JSON object null swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, native

I'm having a hard time checking if this JSON object is null. Example JSONs with and without customer key.

This is what finalValue equals =

With customer key:

```
{
  "customer" : { 
      "href" : "myURL"
  },
  "token": "781hjasf98123bjwef8"
}
```

without customer key:

```
{ 
    "error" : {
        "message" : "Unauthorized"
    }
}
```

This is how I try to check, but it always goes to else statement.

```
            if let value = response.result.value{
                let finalValue = JSON(value)
                if finalValue["customer"] is NSNull{
                    print("if part")
                }else{
                    print("Else part")
                }
            }
```

Comment: Is that you solved problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Swift 3.0

Using SwiftyJSON, there is function `exists()` for checking key is exist or not.

```
if let value = response.result.value {
        let finalValue = JSON(value)
        if finalValue["customer"].exists() {
            print("if value exists then this part will be executed")
        } else {
            print("if value no longer then this part will be executed")
        }
 }
```

Without SwiftyJSON

```
if let value = response.result.value {
        if dictionary.index(forKey: "customer") != nil {
            print("if value exists then this part will be executed")
        } else {
            print("if value no longer then this part will be executed")
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use **optional chaining**:

```
if let finalValue = finalValue["customer"] as? String {
    // there's a value!
}
```